How to pass requested headers with webpack5 proxy?
I have a reactjs app with webpack5. There is a CORS problem. I use webpack devServer with proxy. But the main problem is webpack proxy doesn't pass original headers which is needed for authorization.
The config is:
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 8099,
    allowedHosts: "all",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
    proxy : [
        {
            context: ['/backend'],
            target: "http://mybackend.com",
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
      }
    ]
  }

The callback onProxyReq has no effect:
onProxyReq: (proxyReq) => {
    proxyReq.setHeader('my_header_name', 'value');
 }

And such example also doesn't work:
proxy : [
    {
        context: ['/backend'],
        target: "http://mybackend.com",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        **headers: {"some_header": "value"}**
     }
]

My requests are being successfully sent now but without requested headers. And it's need dynamically passing all requested headers.
This problem occurs when webpack returns 301 redirects.

I solved this problem using the bypass function.
I'm not sure if this is correct, but it works.
proxy : [
    {
        context: ['/backend'],
        target: "http://mybackend.com",
        bypass: (req) => {
                    req.headers['some_header_1'] = 'some_header';
                    req.headers['some_header_2'] = 'some_header';
                },
     }
]

